# PySpark SparkContext Name Error 'sc' in jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am new for pyspark and want to use pyspark using Ipython notebook in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Below are the configuration for pyspark and Ipython notebook.

```
sparkuser@Ideapad:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

# Path for Spark
sparkuser@Ideapad:~$ ls /home/sparkuser/spark/
bin    CHANGES.txt  data  examples  LICENSE   NOTICE  R          RELEASE  scala-2.11.6.deb
build  conf         ec2   lib       licenses  python  README.md  sbin     spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
```

I installed Anaconda2 4.0.0 and path for anaconda:

```
sparkuser@Ideapad:~$ ls anaconda2/
bin  conda-meta  envs  etc  Examples  imports  include  lib  LICENSE.txt  mkspecs  pkgs  plugins  share  ssl  tests
```

Create PySpark Profile for IPython.

```
ipython profile create pyspark

sparkuser@Ideapad:~$ cat .bashrc

export SPARK_HOME="$HOME/spark"
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"
# added by Anaconda2 4.0.0 installer
export PATH="/home/sparkuser/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

Create a file named ~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py:

```
sparkuser@Ideapad:~$ cat .ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py 
import os
import sys

spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "/python")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))

filename = os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py')
exec(compile(open(filename, "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'))

spark_release_file = spark_home + "/RELEASE"

if os.path.exists(spark_release_file) and "Spark 1.5.2" in open(spark_release_file).read():
    pyspark_submit_args = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "")
    if not "pyspark-shell" in pyspark_submit_args: 
        pyspark_submit_args += " pyspark-shell"
        os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args
```

Logging in to pyspark terminal:

```
sparkuser@Ideapad:~$ ~/spark/bin/pyspark
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/04/22 21:06:55 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.2
16/04/22 21:07:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.2
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015 18:08:32)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> sc
<pyspark.context.SparkContext object at 0x7facb75b50d0>
>>>
```

When I run the below command, a juypter browser is opened

```
sparkuser@Ideapad:~$ ipython notebook --profile=pyspark
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook`... continue in 5 sec. Press Ctrl-C to quit now.
[W 21:32:08.070 NotebookApp] Unrecognized alias: '--profile=pyspark', it will probably have no effect.
[I 21:32:08.111 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/sparkuser
[I 21:32:08.111 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 21:32:08.111 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 21:32:08.111 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

In the browser if I type the following command, it is throwing NameError.

```
In [ ]: print sc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ee8101b8fe58> in <module>()
----> 1 print sc
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

When I run the above command in pyspark terminal, it is outputting the required output, but when I run the same command in jupyter it is throwing the above error.

Above are the configuration settings of pyspark and Ipython. 
How to configure the pyspark with jupyter?

Answer (score 6):

Here is one workaround, I would suggest that you to try without depending on `pyspark` to load context for you:-

Install findspark python package from

```
pip install findspark
```

If you had installed Jupyter Notebook using Anaconda, use the Anaconda Prompt or Terminal instead:

```
 $CONDA_PYTHON_EXE -m pip install findspark
```

Then simply import and initialize the sparkcontext:-

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import os

import pyspark # import pyspark only after findspark

print(sc)
print(spark)
```

Reference: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/findspark

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to have a pyspark kernel try in your terminal :

```
mkdir -p ~/.ipython/kernels/pyspark

nano ~/.ipython/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json
```

then copy the following text :

```
{ 'display_name': 'pySpark (Spark 1.6.1)', 
'language': 'python', 
'argv': [ 
    '/usr/bin/python', // Your python Path
    '-m', 'IPython.kernel', 
    '--profile=pyspark', 
    '-f', 
    '{connection_file}' 
] }
```

and save (ctr + X, y)

You should now have "pyspark" in your jupyter kernels.

**Now either sc already exists in your notebook else (try to call sc in a cell), else try running these lines :**

```
import pyspark
conf = (pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('test').set("spark.executor.memory", "2g").setMaster("local[2]"))
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

You should now have your sc running

Answer (score 0):

Simple suggestion would be to not complicate pyspark installation.

With version > 2.2, you can do a simple `pip install pyspark` to install pyspark package.
Additionally, if you want to install jupyter as well, do another pip install for jupyter.

`pip install pyspark
pip install jupyter`

Alternatively, if you want to use another version or a specific distribution for spark, the earlier `3 minute` method would be:
https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f